# How to access specific row in GridView and change its property?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

On page load I am executing these lines of code:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvRD.Rows

         If dt.Rows(0).Item("AKCIJA").ToString = "unos" Then

            Dim myListBox As ImageButton = DirectCast(row.FindControl("btn"), ImageButton)
            myListBox.ImageUrl = "~/Images/no_edit.png"
            myListBox.Enabled = False

         End If

Next
```

With this I am changing ImageUrl on each row, whether it is or not like "unos", but I only want to change rows with AKCIJA = "unos".

This is how looks like GridView:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvRD" Width="1100px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                          OnPageIndexChanging="gvRD_PageIndexChanging"
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged= "OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                          OnRowCommand="gvRD_RowCommand"> 

                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" FirstPageText="First" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" 
                               LastPageText="Last" PreviousPageImageUrl="~/Images/previous_1.png"  NextPageImageUrl="~/Images/next_1.png"/>
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EFEFEF" Wrap="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                     Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Bold="False"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" Wrap="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                          Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Bold="False"></RowStyle>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" Wrap="False" Font-Italic="False"
                             Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Bold="False"></HeaderStyle>

                <Columns>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >    
                         </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="LK" HeaderText="LK" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False">  
                         </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="LIK" HeaderText="LIK" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >                      
                         </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="DN" HeaderText="DN" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" >
                         </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" CommandName="EditRow" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID")%>' ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" Enabled="true" />
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the field "AKCIJA" in the DataKeyNames of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRD" runat="server" DataKeyNames="AKCIJA" ... >
```

you can retrieve the value of the field for each row:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvRD.Rows
    If gvRD.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("AKCIJA").ToString() = "unos" Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvRD.Rows
     Dim myListBox As ImageButton = DirectCast(row.FindControl("btn"), ImageButton) 
     If myListBox.ImageUrl = "unos" Then
        myListBox.ImageUrl = "~/Images/no_edit.png"
        myListBox.Enabled = False
     End If
Next
```

Comment: "unos" is just a value in a column AKCIJA. I have DataTable which I use to fill GridVIew and in the GriedView I have a control ImageButton which should be for every row Enabled = False where find AKCIJA= "unos".

Comment: Can you post the code for adding "btn" to the row. Are you doing this with a custom DataGridViewColumn class?